# $elemMatch queries in mongodb return different result when used with emended documents

Tags: mongodb

I have collection of visitors. Each visitor contains brand id and trans array that has documents like {ct: Date, total: Number}. I try to get visitors that have transaction between two dates... Also I have index on {brandid:1, trans.ct:1} Here are my queries:

```
/*1*/
db.visitors.find({
brandid:12,
'trans':{
    $elemMatch:{
        ct:{
            $gte:ISODate("2015-01-17"),
            $lt:ISODate("2015-01-18")
        }
       }
    }
})
.hint("transct")


/*2*/
db.visitors.find({
brandid:12,
'trans.ct':{
    $elemMatch:{

        $gte:ISODate("2015-01-17"),
        $lt:ISODate("2015-01-18")

       }
    }
})
.hint("transct")
```

The first query returns 42 documents and the second one 0

Here are explains to above queries

```
/* 1 */
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "m.visitors",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "trans" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "ct" : {
                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "ct" : {
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-17T00:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "brandid" : {
                    "$eq" : 12
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "trans" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "ct" : {
                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "ct" : {
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-17T00:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "brandid" : 1,
                    "trans.ct" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "transct",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "brandid" : [ 
                        "[12.0, 12.0]"
                    ],
                    "trans.ct" : [ 
                        "(true, new Date(1421539200000))"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 42,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 99,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 78999,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 38063,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "nReturned" : 42,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 100,
        "works" : 79000,
        "advanced" : 42,
        "needTime" : 78957,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "saveState" : 617,
        "restoreState" : 617,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "trans" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "ct" : {
                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "ct" : {
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-17T00:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 42,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 100,
            "works" : 79000,
            "advanced" : 42,
            "needTime" : 78957,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 617,
            "restoreState" : 617,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 38063,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 38063,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 60,
                "works" : 79000,
                "advanced" : 38063,
                "needTime" : 40936,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 617,
                "restoreState" : 617,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "brandid" : 1,
                    "trans.ct" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "transct",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "brandid" : [ 
                        "[12.0, 12.0]"
                    ],
                    "trans.ct" : [ 
                        "(true, new Date(1421539200000))"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 78999,
                "dupsTested" : 78999,
                "dupsDropped" : 40936,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "allPlansExecution" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "linux-jxch",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.0.0",
    "gitVersion" : "a841fd6394365954886924a35076691b4d149168"
}
}


/* 2 */
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "m.visitors",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "trans.ct" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "" : {
                            "$lt" : ISODate("2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "" : {
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-17T00:00:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "brandid" : {
                    "$eq" : 12
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "trans.ct" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "" : {
                            "$lt" : ISODate("2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "" : {
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-17T00:00:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "brandid" : 1,
                    "trans.ct" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "transct",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "brandid" : [ 
                        "[12.0, 12.0]"
                    ],
                    "trans.ct" : [ 
                        "[new Date(1421452800000), new Date(1421539200000))"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 0,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 42,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 42,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
        "works" : 43,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 42,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "saveState" : 0,
        "restoreState" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "trans.ct" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "" : {
                            "$lt" : ISODate("2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z")
                        },
                        "" : {
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-17T00:00:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 43,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 42,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 42,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 42,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 43,
                "advanced" : 42,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "brandid" : 1,
                    "trans.ct" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "transct",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "brandid" : [ 
                        "[12.0, 12.0]"
                    ],
                    "trans.ct" : [ 
                        "[new Date(1421452800000), new Date(1421539200000))"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 42,
                "dupsTested" : 42,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "allPlansExecution" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "linux-jxch",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.0.0",
    "gitVersion" : "a841fd6394365954886924a35076691b4d149168"
}
}
```

How to force the first query to use index, or how to force second query to return right data?

Here is example of data returned by the 1st query:

```
 /* 40 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54cbfbe06f352a17778b483d"),
"brandid" : NumberLong(12),
"trans" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "54cbfbcd6f352a09778b481e",
        "ct" : ISODate("2015-01-17T18:55:29.000Z"),
        "t" : 891.09
    }
]
}

/* 41 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54cbfbe16f352a17778b4b8b"),
"brandid" : NumberLong(12),
"trans" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "54cbfbcd6f352a09778b481f",
        "ct" : ISODate("2015-01-17T18:59:24.000Z"),
        "t" : 689.45
    }
]
}
```

The 2nd query does not return any documents.

Also "transct" index looks like:

```
 {
   "brandid" : 1,
   "trans.ct" : 1
 }
```

The visitor collection has over 900K documents. Most of them look the same as from above example, but have different brand id and of course "ct" dates in trans array.

Comment: I believe the second query is returning the right data - it's just not behaving how you expect. Can you edit the question to include one or two document that match the first query but do not match the second as expected? I will use them to try to explain the difference between the queries and the index usage.

Comment: added example documents returned by the first query, the second query returns 0 documents